# Cumulative sum in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This is my table as dataframe:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 
1      1    1    1   137  500  11
1      1    1    1   120  500  11
1      1    2    1   101  500  11
1      1    3    1   55   500  11
1      2    2    1   133  340  12
1      2    2    1   125  340  12
1      2    1    1   63   340  12
```

I have to update the data frame using difference between col6 value and cumulative sum of col5 upto that particular row and store that value in separate column called 'updated'.Cumulative sum should be upto the value in Col7  As an example:
col8 values will be:

```
col8
(500-137)
(500-137-120)
(500-137-120-101)
(500-137-120-101-55)
(340-133)
(340-133-125)
(340-133-125-63)
```

Could you please suggest some solution?
I have to use python pandas.

Comment: Which database? M?YSql or SQLServer?

Comment: Wait, if you're doing this data manipulation in Pandas, then why is this question tagged with [mysql] and [sql-server]?

Comment: my question is mainly for pandas forum.

Comment: but if i want solution for mysql or sql server also

Comment: @JackManey   i have tried cumsum() operation on column 5. but i know it's not correct. as i am new in python i need help

Comment: So, why did `cumsum` not give you what you want?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Its for `SQL Server`

**SAMPLE TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP(col1 INT, col2 INT, col3 INT, col4 INT, col5 INT, col6 INT, col7 INT)

INSERT INTO #TEMP
SELECT 1,      1,    1,    1,   137,  500,  11
UNION ALL
SELECT 1,      1,    1,    1,   120,  500,  11
UNION ALL
SELECT 1,      1,    2,    1,   101,  500,  11
UNION ALL
SELECT 1,      1,    3,    1,   55,   500,  11
UNION ALL
SELECT 1,      2,    2,    1,   133,  340,  12
UNION ALL
SELECT 1,      2,    2,    1,   125,  340,  12
UNION ALL
SELECT 1,      2,    1,    1,   63,   340,  12
```

**QUERY**

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
   -- Retrieve row number for each type of COL6 in default order
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY COL6 ORDER BY (SELECT 0))rNO,*
   FROM #TEMP
)
-- Append current COL6 with each items 
SELECT col1 , col2, col3 , col4 , col5 , col6 , col7,
'(' + CAST(C2.COL6 AS VARCHAR(200))+'-'+
-- Retrives comma separated values of previous COL5 values 
-- for each type in COL6
SUBSTRING(
            (SELECT                  
            REPLACE (', ' + CAST(COL6 AS VARCHAR(200)) + '-' + CAST(COL5 AS VARCHAR(200)),', '+CAST(COL6 AS VARCHAR(200)),'')
            FROM CTE   
            WHERE RNO<=C2.RNO AND COL6=C2.COL6
            ORDER BY RNO
            FOR XML PATH('')),2,200000) +')' COL8
FROM CTE C2
```

- [Click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f0617/3) to view result

**EDIT :**

If you want running total and store in `COL8`, you can try the below query

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
   -- Retrieve row number for each type of COL6 in default order
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY COL6 ORDER BY (SELECT 0))rNO,*
   FROM #TEMP
)
SELECT col1 , col2, col3 , col4 , col5 , col6 , col7,
(
     SELECT SUM(COL5)+col6 
     FROM CTE   
     WHERE RNO<=C2.RNO AND COL6=C2.COL6
     GROUP BY col6
)COL8
FROM CTE C2
```

- [Click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/83056/1) to view result

**EDIT 2 : Updated with update query for the table**

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
   -- Retrieve row number for each type of COL6 in default order
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY COL6 ORDER BY (SELECT 0))rNO,*
   FROM #TEMP
)
UPDATE #TEMP SET COL8 = TAB.COL8 
FROM
(
    SELECT col1 , col2, col3 , col4 , col5 , col6 , col7,
    (
       SELECT SUM(COL5)+col6 
       FROM CTE   
       WHERE RNO<=C2.RNO AND COL6=C2.COL6
       GROUP BY col6
    )COL8
    FROM CTE C2
)TAB
WHERE TAB.COL5=#TEMP.COL5 AND TAB.COL6=#TEMP.COL6
```

- [Click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/64b31/2) to view result

Comment: If you have got the result, please mark this as answer on clicking the **TICK** button on the left side of the answer so that the next one who see the question can identify the answer @Anik Mukherjee

Answer (score 3):

I think your attempt to use `cumsum` may not have worked because you didn't group by `col7`- it's apparent from your example calculations that you only calculate the cumulative sum within each value of `col7`, so I think you want:

```
df['cumsums'] = df.groupby('col7')['col5'].cumsum()

df['updated'] = df['col6'] - df['cumsums']

df
Out[8]: 
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6  col7  updated  cumsums
0     1     1     1     1   137   500    11      363      137
1     1     1     1     1   120   500    11      243      257
2     1     1     2     1   101   500    11      142      358
3     1     1     3     1    55   500    11       87      413
4     1     2     2     1   133   340    12      207      133
5     1     2     2     1   125   340    12       82      258
6     1     2     1     1    63   340    12       19      321
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. To find `running total` there are different ways.

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT *,
                Row_number()OVER(partition BY col6 ORDER BY col6)rn
         FROM   Yourtable) As Col8
SELECT *,
       col6 - (SELECT Sum(b.col5)
               FROM   cte b
               WHERE  a.col6 = b.col6
                      AND b.rn <= a.rn)
FROM   cte a;
```

If you are using `Sql Server 2012+` then try this.

```
WITH cte
     AS (SELECT *,
                Row_number()OVER(partition BY col6 ORDER BY col6)rn
         FROM   Yourtable)
SELECT *,
       col6 - Sum(col5)
                OVER(partition BY col6 ORDER BY col6 rows UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) As Col8
FROM   cte a
```

[**SqlFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6e5d8/1)